# Mysql error while running mysql command on the terminal

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

When I run mysql command on my terminal I get this error below, I have been searching for days and many solutions given was related to symbolic link of `/lib/` but none of the solutions worked for me. I'm out of options.

Here is the error:

[image: Console error message]

> mysql: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: did you tried to install lib32ncurses5 for 32bits?

Comment: Please read the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005654/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libncurses-so-5

Comment: Yes i did. but no output

Comment: Well thank you @Rahimkhanabdul, I came across that thread. what I finally did was using MySQL on Xampp to do my work.