# libncurses.so.5 library missing in UBUNTU 22.04 installation for ARM64 (rapsberry PI 4)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, arm, lib

I'm trying to run some 32bit application using wine and Box86 on UBUNTU 22.04 64bit and it seems that libncurses.so.5:i386 are missing. I tried to install those libraries as per this stack exchange question

[error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005654/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libncurses-so-5)

but all those tips are failing

```
krzysztof@krzysiaczekpi1:~$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386
[sudo] password for krzysztof:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5:i386

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs


Box86 with Dynarec v0.2.7 e9fcef3d built on Aug 21 2022 00:07:30
Box86 with Dynarec v0.2.7 e9fcef3d built on Aug 21 2022 00:07:30
Error initializing native libncurses.so.5 (last dlerror is libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
Wine cannot find the ncurses library (libncurses.so.5).
```

any idea where to find those libraries 32 bit version for arm architecture ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually download the 32-Bit [libncurses5 package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/i386/libncurses5/download) which contains the "libncurses.so.5" file and as well as any other ubuntu packages you may need from the Ubuntu Package Archive (https://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: No I haven't find this library anywhere and installed win11 on PI as this what I needed

Comment: Where is "here"? (In case the link becomes broken)