# Install ncurses-5 in CentOS 9

Tags: centos, ncurses

I'm using a server that is running CentOS 9 and I'm having issue compiling something that uses libncurses.so.5.
I installed the ncurses-devel package, but it is in version 6, and isn't found by the compiler.
I saw that on CentOS 8, it is possible to install ncurses-compat-libs for that purpose, bit it doesn't seem to be available for CentOS 9.
Is there a way to either install ncurses-compat-libs in CentOS 9, or to install the library through another mean?

Thank you

Comment: Redhat dropped ncurses-compat earlier this year (no real discussion).  You could probably do an rpm-rebuild of the older package srpm.

Comment: Any hint as of how to do that? Or is there a way to manually install it?

Comment: I'd get the srpm (it's simpler...) from [website](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/) and rebuild that, e.g., see [wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM).

Comment: Simply install the `ncurses-compat-libs` package. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50230352/828885).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so per the comment of Thomas Dickey above, I rebuilt the RPM package from the `ncurses-compat-libs<version>.src.rpm` downloaded from [RPM Find](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=ncurses-compat-libs).
After that, I ran `rpmbuild --rebuild ncurses-compat-libs<version>.src.rpm`, which created a bunch of rpm files in `~/rpmbuild/RPMS/<arch>/*.rpm`.
I installed all of them at once using the `sudo dnf localinstall --allowerasing <list of rpms>` to make sure all the dependencies could be resolved.
See the [wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM) provided by Thomas Dickey for more details.
Thanks for the help!